# Snowflake stored procedure: handling multiline strings and single quotes

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using back ticks to build below insert query in Snowflake Stored procedure and it is working fine while firing the sql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_TEST_CALLPROC()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS $$
var q = `insert into abc 
         select col1, col2, 
         to_date(col3,'YYYYMMDD') as col3 from def;`
var insrtSql = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: q});
var result = insrtSql.execute();
result.next()
$$
;
```

I also want to log this query into a log table, which is failing due because of single quotes in the TO_DATE function 'YYYYMMDD':

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_LOAD_LOG_POC(PROCESS_ID FLOAT,
                            PROCESS_NAME STRING,
                            BATCH_ID FLOAT,
                            LOG_TXT STRING)
    RETURNS STRING
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    EXECUTE AS OWNER
    AS $$
 
    var query = `INSERT INTO INGESTION_LOG
                  VALUES
                  (${PROCESS_ID},'${PROCESS_NAME}',${BATCH_ID},current_timestamp(),'${LOG_TXT}');`
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: query});
    var res = stmt.execute();
 $$
;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_TEST_CALLPROC()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS $$
function log(process_id,process_name,batch_id,log_txt){
        snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: `call SP_LOAD_LOG_POC(:1,:2,:3,:4)`, binds:[process_id,process_name,batch_id,log_txt] } ).execute();
        }

var q = `insert into abc 
         select col1, col2, 
         to_date(col3,'YYYYMMDD') as col3 from def;`
log(1,'test_procedure',12345,`Firing insert query : ${q}`);
var insrtSql = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: q});
var result = insrtSql.execute();
result.next()
$$
;

CALL SP_TEST_CALLPROC()

Execution error in store procedure SP_TEST_CALLPROC: 
Execution error in store procedure SP_LOAD_LOG_POC: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 5 at position 23 unexpected 'YYYYMMDD'.
At Statement.execute, line 10 position 19 
At Statement.execute, line 4 position 169
```

Tried using javascript function replaceAll() to replacing single quote to 2 single quotes (' -> '') but this function is not supported inside Snowflake Stored proc.
Can anyone suggested how to get rid of this error while inserting the log entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to pass SQL as a string to another function, UDF, or SP, there are a number of special characters to consider in addition to single ticks. Here are a couple of JavaScript helper functions I wrote to make different data types safe for inserts.

Since the wrapInsertValue function calls escapeInsertString for text types, you can just call that one. The point of the wrapInsertValue function is to read the type for the column and handle it accordingly. Note that the escapeInsertString function will also compact whitespace. You can comment out the line `s = s.replace(/\s+/g, " ");` if you don't want to do that.

```
function wrapInsertValue(value, dataType){
    if (value == 'null'){
        return 'NULL';
    }
    switch (dataType){
        case "TEXT":
            return "'" + escapeInsertString(value) + "'";
        case "OBJECT":
            return "'" + escapeInsertString(value) + "'";
        case "TIMESTAMP_TZ":
            return "'" + value + "'";
        case "TIMESTAMP":
            return "'" + value + "'";
        default: return value;
    }
}

function escapeInsertString(value) {
    var s = value.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");
    s = s.replace(/'/g, "''" );
    s = s.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
    s = s.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
//  s = s.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "");
    return s;
}
```